# Oracle 19C - Corrupt webservice response / corrupt file download

Tags: oracle

We are using Oracle 19C and call a webservice that mainly returns a base 64 encoded PDF. At one of our customers sites we get the first approximately 32k Bytes response the way it should be, and after that the result is corrupted.

We have managed to isolate the issue a lot further:

- The issue can be reproduced by simply downloading any file from the webserver. For this purpose, I made a file called "test.txt" which is roughly 300k Bytes in size and only contains the letter "A" over and over.
- The issue is independent of the webserver, it doesn't matter where the file is hosted.
- The issue still happens when the Oracle server and the webserver are in the same subnet (no firewall in between)
- The issue does NOT happen when this file is downloaded from a browser on the Oracle database server
- Juggling around different buffer sizes results in different behavior. But at around 40k Bytes latest, the file becomes completely corrupted.
- UTL_HTTP.SET_PERSISTENT_CONN_SUPPORT makes no difference
- The problem does NOT happen when using http instead of https
- When downloading the same file with the same code multiple times in a row, the resulting file is never the same
- The problem can only be reproduced on a particular server/customer. Our development server running Oracle 19.8 (same OS, same bundle patch) does not show this behavior.
- The file has the correct size. Only the contents get scrambled.

I'm fairly sure it's not the customers firewall, because it still happens when the webserver and the db server are on the same subnet.
I'm fairly sure it's not any security software on the server, because it works in SoapUI and a browser.
I'm fairly sure it's not Oracle 19.8 per se, because it works for us.

We have isolated the code that reads the web response in chunks and assembles the blob, but then I also noticed you can actually download files even simpler by calling httpurityp.createuri(url).getblob(). I tried with this code and the issue still persists, so it's not our code (that's tried and tested anyway) either.

Here's the code:

```
declare
 l_blob           BLOB;
  url_v             VARCHAR2(250) := 'http://www.infosystem.ch/files/test.txt';
BEGIN
  l_blob := HTTPURITYPE.createuri(url_v).getblob();

  INSERT INTO test_file_download
    ( download_at    
    , content)
  VALUES
    ( SYSDATE
    , l_blob
    );            

END;
/
```

This should result the file http://www.infosystem.ch/files/test.txt, which only contains the letter "A" over and over.

It doesn't, the resulting file is corrupted: https://www.infosystem.ch/files/test_corrupted.txt

Side by side:

[Corrupted image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc4qK.png)

Then there are a few more, and at some stage (usually around 32k) the rest of the file becomes a mess:

[Beginning of the rest of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcG8F.png)

Does anyone have any idea what this could be? I've already logged an SR with Oracle, but last time we had a similar issue (back in 12.2) it took them 6 months to reproduce and acknowledge that it's a bug, and 5 years later "development as still working on a fix". Needless to say, that's completely worthless.

Thanks!

Comment: We had similar issues, IMHO utl_http using https is broken on windows :( I suspect that the guilty one is actually the Dell BSAFE Micro-Edition Suite MES library embedded into the DB. I've upgraded to 19.11 (windows) and get "ORA-29013: SSL MAC verification failure" when requesting `https://www.google.com`

Answer (score 1):

"CORE Patch for Bug# 32327201 for 19.0.0.0.0 Windows-x86-64 Platforms
This patch is non-RAC Rolling Installable.
Released: Thu June  10 11:24:26 2021

This document describes how you can install the CORE DST patch for bug#  32327201 on your Oracle Database 19 Release 19.0.0.0.0"

This is the one that solved our problem today, that was released 3 days ago :)

I think that we had the same issue as you did :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is in fact solved by patch 32738356

32738356 - KBHSHTRECEIVE GETTING CORRUPTED DATA ON WINDOWS